# salesforce: Is it possible to override Salesforce global search?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

There's a search box on the top of Salesforce. Is it possible to override(re-implement) it? Like catching the click event, popping up dialog, or customizing the search result page...

I went over the Visualforce development guide, it seems I can't do this with Visualforce. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use custom sidebar components.
In one of them place javascript that will intercept the events from the global search -> and make that event invoke whatever you want.